# Protocol with associated type as property

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Is it possible to use protocol with associated type as a property to match some constraints?

Here is an example which I'm struggling with:

```
protocol Animal {

    associatedtype Item

    func doSomething(with item: Item)
}

class Owner<Item> {

    var item: Item
    // I have to be sure that Animal.Item == Item
    var animal: Animal
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Protocols with associated types cannot be used as the type of a property. Instead of constraining `animal`'s type, you can try constraining the generic type of `Owner`:

```
class Owner<AnimalType> where AnimalType : Animal {
    var item: AnimalType.Item?
    var animal: AnimalType?
}
```

You don't need `Item` because you can just use `AnimalType.Item` for this. That's just how associated types work. Say you want a function that accepts an `Item`, you can just use `AnimalType.Item` in place of that:

```
func someFunc(someParameter: AnimalType.Item) { ... }
```

Or maybe this might fit your needs?

```
class Owner<AnimalType, ItemType> where AnimalType : Animal, AnimalType.Item == ItemType {
    var item: ItemType?
    var animal: AnimalType?
}
```

Comment: I think your answer needs some improvements. Notice that I want to have Item in Owner and Item in Animal be the same. I updated question which requires that.

Comment: @Nominalista For the `item` property you can just use `AnimalType.Item` as the type.

Comment: @Nominalista I think you need to rethink how you are going to model your classes and protocols. I see that you have a Java background. Swift protocols with associated types is not an equivalent of Java's "generic interfaces". They cannot be used as the type of a property.

Comment: AnimalType.Item solved the problem. Had to remodel a little bit, but now works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 5.7 there is now a concept of a "primary" `associatedtype` which allows you to do this:

```
protocol Animal<Item> {
   associatedtype Item 
   func doSomething(with item: Item)
}
```

You then set it as a property like this:

```
class Owner<Item> {
    var item: Item
    var animal: any Animal<Item>
}
```

See https://www.donnywals.com/what-are-primary-associated-types-in-swift-5-7/